# how to extract xml value field with in sql server ( extractvalue function in mysql )

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xml, extract

I have to extract xml value with in sql server. Normally when I extract value field that stored in mysql I can just simply use `extractvalue(data,'parent/child/node') as value`

Can anyone tell me how can do this in sql server ? thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
declare @x xml = '<foo><bar>my value</bar></foo>'

select @x.value('(/foo/bar)[1]', 'varchar(30)')
```

The same will work for an XML column as well.