# Operator ExtractValue() equivalent between MySQL and SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a DataBase migration between MySQL and SQL Server 2012, however i have none knowledge in MySQL own functions, can any one please tell me what would be an equivalent on SQL Server for this code

```
ExtractValue(@source, 'count(/s:Envelope/s:Body/CancelaCFDResponse/CancelaCFDResult/Folios)')
```

Comment: [how to extract xml value field with in sql server ( extractvalue function in mysql )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485110/how-to-extract-xml-value-field-with-in-sql-server-extractvalue-function-in-mys)

Comment: Thanks, i find out MySQL and SQL Server works in different manners, in MySQL you can assing a table to a variable without telling the engine it is a variable table by just using @, weird, and thanks for the help.